# How to make custom forgot controller?

Tags: laravel, authentication, model-view-controller, forgot-password

In laravel, there is auth::routes, but instead of using that, I want to make my own forgot password controller. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`auth::routes()` is just a wrapper, you can find the method `routes()` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` and see all the routes that are added by the method. So basically just remove `auth::route()` and add the routes with your own controllers.

This is some of them:

```
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
```

The routes can vary depending of you version of Laravel.

Comment: when I remove auth::routes , and send the reset link for forget password, it shows send reset link form instead of change password form. I have added these routes